# Backbone model not having attribute after fetch

Tags: backbone.js

So I'm having a problem after I'm fetching a model and trying to render it to a template in this view below. I've searched around and found out that I have to do a `_.bindAll` etc, but still it doesn't work.  Inside the first console.log, where I'm trying to get the User's name, it returns undefined. I tried putting `this.render()` (due to the async nature of fetch) in the success callback but it didn't work. When I inspect what `console.log(data)` yields, I do see the values I want, but it seems that nothing is being passed to the template.

```
 define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/UserModel',
  'text!/assets/templates/dashboard.html'
  ], function($, _, Backbone, UserModel, dashboardTemplate) {

    window.DashboardView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $(".content"),

    initialize: function() {
      _.bindAll(this, 'render');

      this.user = new UserModel();
      this.user.fetch({
        success: console.log(this.user.get("name")),
        error: function(model, response) {
          console.log("error fetching model");
          console.log(model);
          console.log(response);
        }
      });
    },

    render: function() {

      console.log(this);
      var data = {
        user: this.user,
        _: _
      };
      console.log(data);

      var compiledTemplate = _.template(dashboardTemplate, data);
      $(this.el).html(compiledTemplate);
    }
  });

  return DashboardView;

});
```

Could anyone please shed some light?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first issue is that your `console.log` runs right away, not on success.

```
this.user.fetch({
    success: console.log(this.user.get("name")),
    // ...
```

means that you are calling `log` and then passing the return value of that as the `success` callback. You need to pass an anonymous function.

```
var view = this;
this.user.fetch({
    success: function(){
        console.log(view.user.get("name")),
        view.render();
    },
    // ...
```

Second of all, when you render the template, you need to pass it the model's attributes, but currently you are passing the model itself. For this you can use `toJSON` to convert the model to a standard object.

```
var data = {
    user: this.user.toJSON(),
    // ...
```

Comment: I tried using an anonymous function inside the success callback. and calling view.render() as you mentioned. It still logged undefined. But, when I changed to view.user.get("name"), it got the right "this" and logged the correct name. And I was, in fact, missing the conversion to JSON in the end. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @chiurox No prob. Yep, I just forgot to change the other `this` to `view`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check what the value of `this` is inside of your success callback, I doubt that it is the `View` as you expect which is why you are getting an undefined. Inside your template you can call `console.log` for extra debugging.

The main problem I see with your code is that `_.template()` returns a function not static content. Therefore you should be calling `$(this.el).html(compiledTemplate());`.

Passing `data` in the compiledTemplate setting will embed the data and make your template static. You generally should only pass your template code to `_.template` and then call the compiled function like so with the current data: `compiledTemplate(this.user.toJSON());`